# Is it ok to seal the the outside rail of an in-wall AC/heater in the winter?

Tags: heating, air-conditioning

I have an Amana in-wall AC/Heater. In the winter I feel that it creates a draft and allows cool air to sneak in. I'm thinking of taking some heavy duty plastic to the outside rail. Would this impact the heating function of the AC. And if it's possible what's the best material to use and tape that hold outside ?  Pic of the opening below: 
[image]

Comment: is the outside grate removable?

Comment: Many times those are slide in units and some had provisions for sealing them in winter. From the inside one of the fancy ones I installed had an accordion like plastic with magnets that held the plastic in place or folded up but the AC will not work with that in place and the fresh air or outside air intake may be covered but yes they usually can be covered.

Comment: If you get your heat from electric resistance, then you should be able to cover it. If you get heat from a heat pump, then you cannot cover. You have either a PTAC or PTHP unit.  Best to call Amana customer service